# Need to add custom headers to s3 putobject

Tags: aws-sdk

I would be requiring to set some custom headers to the files I am uploading to s3 I can edit the meta data but cannot have custom headers googled up it showed that can be done using middleware any help is most welcomed

Comment: Which language and SDK are you even using?  Show us some example code so far of where you're putting the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a custom header to your file you will have to read and re-write the file after adding the headers.
Some references -

- [add custom attribute or metadata to file java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955475/add-custom-attribute-or-metadata-to-file-java)
- [How can I write metadata into a .JPG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246709/how-can-i-write-metadata-into-a-jpg)

Instead you can create a [Thrift](https://sookocheff.com/post/thrift/so-you-want-to-use-thrift/) object over the object you need to upload and add metadata within the object. The downside to this is that you need to unbox the object before reading (as opposed to a direct S3 bucket link, like the ones used for images, etc).
I have used thrift and avro objects to send encryption related information with an encrypted file to S3, which was later used to decrypt the file based on the info.